# Use ssh over port forwarded connection

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, openssh

My organisation makes us connect to our AWS environments using a "bastion" host so my openssl .ssh config file looks a bit like this:

```
Host bastion.*.c1.some.com
User bastionuser
ProxyCommand none
StrictHostKeyChecking no
ForwardAgent yes

Host *.c1.some.com 12.345.* 456.12.1.*
User awsuser
StrictHostKeyChecking no
ForwardAgent yes
ProxyCommand ~/.ssh/proxy_command.sh %h %p
```

I want to use an ssh client built into the CLion IDE to connect to my AWS environment but it does not support this kind of configuration.

Can I setup a port forward using openssl and then establish an ssh connection over that tunnel from within CLion?

Comment: The config you show and the directory ~/.ssh are for **OpenSSH not OpenSSL**. OpenSSH is a separate project from OpenSSL, and it implements SSH which is a completely different protocol from SSL/TLS (and some others) implemented by OpenSSL. Although some cryptographic operations in these protocols are similar, and for them OpenSSH does use the libcrypto _part_ of OpenSSL (or LibreSSL). Yes, the _OpenSSH_ client program `ssh` can do forwarding if the server (here the bastion) allows it. Show what ~/.ssh/proxy_command.sh does and/or read the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to setup a port forward using PuTTY and afterwards I was able to establish a second ssh connection over the port forward using Intellij. For some reason I couldn't establish the second ssh connection over the OpenSSH port forward, perhaps because the Git Bash environment is sandboxed or something?

Presumably this will also work with any other SSH client that doesn't support tunneling out of the box.